# How to create a std::ofstream to a temp file?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, mkstemp

Okay, `mkstemp` is the preferred way to create a temp file in POSIX.

But it opens the file and returns an `int`, which is a file descriptor. From that I can only create a FILE*, but not an `std::ofstream`, which I would prefer in C++. (Apparently, on AIX and some other systems, you can create an `std::ofstream` from a file descriptor, but my compiler complains when I try that.)

I know I could get a temp file name with `tmpnam` and then open my own ofstream with it, but that's apparently unsafe due to  race conditions, and results in a compiler warning (g++ v3.4. on Linux):

```
warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
```

So, is there any portable way to create an `std::ofstream` to a temp file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
    char *tmpname = strdup("/tmp/tmpfileXXXXXX");
    ofstream f;
    int fd = mkstemp(tmpname);
    f.attach(fd);
```

**EDIT:** Well, this might not be portable. If you can't use attach and can't create a ofstream directly from a file descriptor, then you have to do this:

```
char *tmpname = strdup("/tmp/tmpfileXXXXXX");
mkstemp(tmpname);
ofstream f(tmpname);
```

As *mkstemp* already creates the file for you, race condition should not be a problem here.

Comment: That doesn't compile with my g++ v3.4.4 on Linux. Apparently only some platforms have that function.

Comment: Thanks! For your second method (using mkstemp and then ofstream): Is that still efficient in terms of I/O? That will access the file system twice, right? Our file system is super slow and I'm worried that it will put an unnecessary burden on it.

Comment: `mkstemp` can fail and return -1; your code should catch that case.

Comment: Also the second example is leaking the file descriptor returned by `mkstemp`.

Comment: You need to call `free` after using `strdup` as well.

Comment: `mkstemp` is not portable? `std::tmpfile` is portable, but doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 17):

I've done this function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string open_temp(std::string path, std::ofstream& f) {
    path += "/XXXXXX";
    std::vector<char> dst_path(path.begin(), path.end());
    dst_path.push_back('\0');

    int fd = mkstemp(&dst_path[0]);
    if(fd != -1) {
        path.assign(dst_path.begin(), dst_path.end() - 1);
        f.open(path.c_str(), 
               std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::out);
        close(fd);
    }
    return path;
}

int main() {
    std::ofstream logfile;
    open_temp("/tmp", logfile);
    if(logfile.is_open()) {
        logfile << "hello, dude" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You should probably make sure to call umask with a proper file creation mask (I would prefer 0600)- the manpage for mkstemp says that the file mode creation mask is not standardized. It uses the fact that mkstemp modifies its argument to the filename that it uses. So, we open it and close the file it opened (so, to not have it opened twice), being left with a ofstream that is connected to that file.

Comment: I wonder if it's safe to just use std::string as template and use (char *) dst.path.c_str(). Seems to be fine for most sensible implementations of std::string.

Comment: ididak, it's not safe. the c-string pointed to is not writable :)

Comment: In C++11 a std::string can have it's first entry dereferenced. Thus you can pass &somestring[0]; to a function expecting a char*. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: @X-Istence: Yeah, but be careful in GCC [pre-5.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html): https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199710/560648

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work:

```
char tmpname[256];
ofstream f;
sprintf (tmpname, "/tmp/tmpfileXXXXXX");
int fd = mkstemp(tmpname);
ofstream f(tmpname);
```

I haven't tried it, but you can check.

Answer (score 0):

```
char tempFileName[20]; // name only valid till next invocation of tempFileOpen
ofstream tempFile;
void tempFileOpen()
{
    strcpy(tempFileName, "/tmp/XXXXXX");
    mkstemp(tempFileName);
    tempFile.open(tempFileName);
}
```

This code works for me with GCC/libstdc++6 4.8.4 and Clang 3.9 as well. Thanks to the other replies as well which were helpful to me.