# temporary file stream

Tags: c++, filestream, temporary

I'd like to create a temporary file stream.
Is there a c++ equivalent to C's tmpfile() function.

If not, how would I create one?

Comment: What platform ? If on unix, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499636/c-how-to-create-a-stdofstream-to-a-temp-file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499636/c-how-to-create-a-stdofstream-to-a-temp-file).

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether your implementation offers a `std::fstream` constructor that takes a file descriptor, and if so use `fileno` to get the fd from the `FILE*` returned by `tmpfile()`. But the C++ standard doesn't guarantee that constructor.