# Is accessing a reference to T as an array of T UB?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, undefined-behavior

I'm mostly interested in the general case of:

```
T& tr = SomeSource();
T* tp = &tr;
T t = tp[5];
```

The specific example that provoked this question ([and seems to have been asked befor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169915/is-writing-to-str0-buffer-of-a-stdstring-well-defined-behaviour-in-c11)) is:

```
std::string s = "01234567";
char *c = &s[0];

// Do something with it.
c[4] = 'f';  // Is this valid or undefined behavior
```

Context:

- Writing to std::string::data is explicitly UB.
- std::string::operator[] can return references that writing to is UB (e.g. out of bounds).
- The intent of the motivating case is to avoid a C function to populate a char* and end up with that in a C++ std::string without having to copy it.

Comment: @Praetorian: the question you cited attempt to resolve the specific case I mentioned, but takes as given (and without question) that the answer to the question I asked is "not UB".

Comment: your generic case doesn't make any sense. also, there's no information what the operator `[]` does there.

Comment: I think my reply to your comment on the linked dupe should answer your question. I don't understand your *general case* example. What is `t`? And how are the preceding reference and pointer significant? Can you change that example to using `std::string`? If you feel your question is still unanswered, I'll reopen it for you.

Comment: I think there is a typo, `t[5]` should be `tp[5]`.

Comment: @Oktalist: yes, typo, corrected.