# C++: Safe reading from file with std::string (&str[0]) as a buffer?

Tags: c++, string, allocation

I have a binary file that I'm reading from. In the file at one point, there is a known number of bytes which make up a simple ASCII string (possibly with newlines). Right now I have:

```
void doSomething(istream &in) {
    vector<char> buf(length + 1, '\0');
    in.read(&buf[0], length);
    string str(&buf[0]);
}
```

But I realized that it would probably be faster to do

```
void doSomething(istream &in) {
    string str(length + 1, '\0'); // +1 needed?
    in.read(&str[0], length);
}
```

I tried looking in the standard to see if string allocation is always sequential or if it's safe doing something like this. Safe meaning, no accidental reading into (writing to) memory not part of the string. Does anyone know?

Comment: Define _safe_ more clearly please. Where does `length` come from? How is it calculated?

Comment: length comes from the file, and denotes the "known number of bytes" that are part of the string (as above).

Comment: Duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25169915/241631

Comment: Yes I think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` allocation is always sequential, at least as of C++11. I believe prior to that it wasn't clearly defined so, but no implementations used non-sequential storage.

You do not need to explicitly add space for a null terminator in `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also happen to know if its necessary to include a null-terminator when reading like this, or is it implementation dependent?

Comment: Reading the duplicate question at stackoverflow.com/q/25169915/241631 the answer says "[...] and your code avoids overwriting the terminating NULL character [...]" suggesting it is necessary to include a null character? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @bombax You can write to any index in the range [0, `str.size()`), and `str[str.size() - 1]` does not have to be `'\0'`.

Comment: That's perfectly clear, thanks!