# Is it safe to use std::string::c_str() to modify the underlying std::string?

Tags: c++, stdstring, const-cast, c-str

I came across some code which has several instances of the bellow example:

```
std::string str = "This  is my string";
char* ptr = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());

ptr[5] = 'w';
ptr[6] = 'a';
```

In this simplified example there is an assignment of `std::string::c_str()`, which returns `const char*`, to a `char*` pointer using `const_cast`.

This seems to work as intended and `str` is modified accordingly.

But the description of `std::string::c_str()` in my local library reads as follows:

> *Return const pointer to null-terminated contents. This is a handle to internal data. Do not modify or dire things may happen*.

And in *cppreference* the description includes:

> *Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string.*
>
> ...
>
> *Writing to the character array accessed through `c_str()` is undefined behavior.*

In the standard [[string.accessors]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/string.accessors) the descritpion is similar and no information about this *...null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string...* is provided.

Instead of clarifying the issue, this confused me further, what character array? How is it equivalent? Is it a copy? And if so why is modifying it, also modifying the original string? Is this implementation defined?

I would like to avoid the task of altering all the instances of the code where this is used, so my question is:

Is there any way this can be correct, can it be legal to use `ptr` pointer to modify `str` string?

Comment: nope, just because it happens to work doesn't mean its not undefined behaviour, change `c_str` to `data` to fix it

Comment: @AlanBirtles, that is my understanding also, but I was hopping that there was some way this could be correctly used.

Comment: In older standards, `std::string` was much more free-form than it is after C++11. The implementation was allowed to do (but rarely did) extremely strange things to produce the character array returned by `c_str`.

Comment: @anastaciu Always be extremely careful what you're doing with `const_cast` (it's often enough as bad as `reinterpret_casr`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, yes, my original instintcts are to steer clear of this type of construct, unfortulnately I will have to deal with it nevertheless.

Comment: Use `str.data()` instead, it returns a non-const pointer. Or `&str.front()` or `&str[0]`, if you are sure the string is not empty. All these produce a modifiable pointer to the string's buffer.

Comment: @anastaciu [Does this answer your question](/questions/29347041/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-length-of-a-stdstring-without-modifying-the-buffer-c)?  Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169915/is-writing-to-str0-buffer-of-a-stdstring-well-defined-behaviour-in-c11)?

Comment: Yes, the standard is quite clear that it's UB. But I wouldn't expect it to break in real world.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yes, it does seem that that is the correct approach.

Comment: Meh. `vector<char>` + `string_view` tbh

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, more or less, though those are nice links they don't mention the use of `c_str`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes it does seem that way.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, I'm content with the easiest fix, I regret having found this in the first place :)

Comment: Well I mean in general :P

Comment: @user4581301, I missed your comment, thanks for the insight, in any case, with the array of options provided to do this in a similar but correct way, it's just strange why this was coded like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference for [`c_str`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/string.accessors#3) that you cited is quite clear on the matter:

> The program shall not modify any of the values stored in the character array; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The fact that it happens to work doesn't mean anything. Undefined behavior means the program could do the "right" thing if it wants to.

---

If you do want to modify the underlying data, you can use the non-const overload of [`data()`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/string.accessors#6), which is available from C++17, which allows you to modify all but the null-terminator:

> The program shall not modify the value stored at p + size() to any value other than charT(); otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Well spotted, it does seem a good way to go, my goal is to mess as little as possible wth the existing code.

Comment: Yes, simply replacing `c_str` with `data` should work. (though I believe this is only true from c++17).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check that.

Comment: Are you sure about that? because the standard clearly said: "Modifying the character array accessed through the const overload of data has undefined behavior." Since c++ 11/14 only have data() return const char*, the standard forbid to use data() to modify underlying string.

Comment: @Dexter If the string is not const, then the non-const overlad of `data` is called, and modifying the contents through that is perfectly valid I think.

Comment: @cigien but c++11/14 does not have non-const overload of `data`.

Comment: @Dexter Oh, I see what you mean. Good point, I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: @cigien then I think the only choice for c++11/14 should be `&str[0]`. Might also worth to mention :)

Comment: @Dexter Hmm, true, but I prefer not adding solutions that need to work with older standards, unless the OP explicitly asks for it. I think C++17 is sufficiently widespread enough, that future visitors will not need an older solution. I'm an optimist, YMMV :)