# C++11: Does an assignment operator prevent a type from being POD, and thus being global-initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Background: I'm in a large-code environment where the undefined order in which global constructors are run is problematic.  So I have a custom class that is designed to delay initialization until first-use.  All its magic occurs inside its operator* and operator-> functions; they're the only thing defined.  It also stores some state within itself, to make available to the automatic-initialization function.  That state must, of course, be POD, so that the whole class is POD, so that it can be completely set up before anyone's code starts running, so that all code everywhere can use all globals everywhere, without fear that the globals haven't been set up yet.

A while back someone added a private, never-defined assignment operator, so that the type would never be assigned to (it's not designed to ever change anyway).  Now someone else is saying the class is broken because it's not POD.  If instead of it being declared-but-not-defined, I declare it as "=delete", I'm thinking that's somehow better.  And indeed, with that change, std::is_pod<>::value returns true for the type.

But does as assignment operator prevent a type from being POD?  I thought the requirements were just that it had to have only public data members, no virtual methods, and no constructor or destructor.

And more to the point for my situation: does the presence of a never-defined assignment operator prevent the class from being able to be initialized at global initialization time, along with all the other global PODs?

Reduced example:

```
struct LazyString {
  const char *c_str;

  bool has_been_inited;
  string *lazy_str_do_not_use_directly;

  string &operator*() { return *get(); }
  string *operator->() { return get(); }

 private:
  string *get() {
    // The real code uses a mutex, of course, to be thread-safe.
    if (!has_been_inited) {
      lazy_str_do_not_use_directly = new string(c_str);
      has_been_inited = true;
    }
    return lazy_str_do_not_use_directly;
  }

  // Does this make the class non-POD?
  // If so, does that mean that global variables of this type
  // will not be initialized at global-initialization time, that wonderful
  // moment in time where no code has yet been run?
  void operator=(const LazyString&);

  // If I do this instead, it breaks C++03 compatibility, but is this somehow better?
  void operator=(const LazyString&) = delete;
};

LazyString lazy = { "lazy" };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << *lazy;
}
```

Comment: Brewing your own heap memory management is almost never a good idea. Why do you think you need this? (did you mean to implement s.th. similar as [copy-on-write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11))

Comment: You are confusing POD-ness and static initialization. Neither is dependent on the other.

Comment: Since all of the data members are publicly visible, that declaration makes up a POD, yes. **NOTE:** You'll experience unwanted side effects regarding the `new string(c_str);` in your _lazy initialization_, when copying/assigning this POD type around.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There's more to being POD than having public data members.

Comment: `if (std::is_pod<LazyString>::value) ...` from `#include <type_traits>` will tell you if the compiler's library thinks the type is POD or not.

Comment: @MikeSeymour _"A POD type must be _trivial_; ..."_ Ahh yes, agreed! The type declared by the OP isn't _trivial_.

Comment: This is a side issue, but the fact that a declared member function (including an assignment operator) is not defined or used in the translation unit is not really relevant, because the function could be defined and used in some other translation units. You can't tell until link-time. If the member function is private and there are no non-inline member functions, I suppose it is theoretically possible to know that there cannot be a use in some other TU, but it's not incumbent on the compiler to do this analysis. So `= delete` is clearer, and therefore IMHO "better".

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ : I need this because, well, let's say I have two files.

    file1.cc:  string str = "Hello World";
    file2.cc:  int p = printf("%s\n", str.c_str());

In C++, I don't know what will get printed.  But if I say:

    file1.cc:  LazyString str = { "Hello World" };
    file2.cc:  int p = printf("%s\n", str->c_str());

Now I can be sure that Hello World will be printed.  Because LazyString is enough of a POD to be initialized at constant-initialization time.  My question is, what is the definition of "enough of a POD to be initializaed at constant-initialization time"?

Answer (score 8):

> Does an assignment operator prevent a type from being POD

Yes. A POD type must be *trivial*; and so must be *trivially copyable*; and so must have no non-trivial copy or move assignment operators.

Any user-provided operator is non-trivial, so declaring the copy constructor makes the class non-trivial, and hence non-POD.

> and thus being global-initialized?

No. Any instantiable type, POD or not, can be a global variable.

**UPDATE**: From the comment, you meant to ask:

> Can it be statically, rather than dynamically, initialised?

Yes, since it has a trivial constructor; as long as the initialiser is a constant expression. In your example, `{ "lazy" }` is a constant expression, so `LazyString` can be statically initialised.

The important feature here is that it has a trivial constructor, not that it's POD. POD means it also meets various other requirements, not relevant to initialisation.

Comment: I believe the correct sentence is "Any user-**provided** operator is non-trivial". For instance, `class foo { foo& operator =(foo const&) = default; };` has a trivial user-declared copy assignment operator.

Comment: @CassioNeri: Thanks for the correction. It's easy to lose track of these shades of meaning.

Comment: You said "Any instantiable type, can be a global variable", and while true, that doesn't answer my question. For example, if I have foo1.cc, containing the global initialization "int foo = printf("Hello World\n");", and also foo2.cc, containing the global initialization "extern int foo; int bar = foo;", then I can't know, per the C++ standard, what value bar will end up with, because both of those are dynamic initializations.  That's why I'm trying to eliminate any and all dynamic initializations... but I don't know if the fact that I'm assigning all fields of this struct with PODs is enough.

Comment: @jorgbrown: Sorry, I just answered the question you asked, and failed to guess what you meant. I've updated with the answer you (hopefully) wanted.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has several stages of initialization for non-local variables with static storage duration (global variable fall into this category) - regardless of whether the type is a POD or not.

- zero initialization takes place before any other initialization
- constant initialization takes place
- dynamic initialization

The first two types of initialization must take place before dynamic initialization.  Dynamic initialization is the situation where the order of initialization can be difficult to set.  Some dynamic initialization is unordered, some is ordered within a translation unit, etc.

Even if you global variable is not POD, you can be sure that zero initialization will have taken place before any dynamic init.

See C++11 3.6.2 "Initialization of non-local variables" for details.

Comment: As I understand it, dynamic initialization can reference globals from other files.  As an author of another file, I want to be sure my globals are available to all dynamic initialization vars.  That is, I want to be sure that my class is initialized at constant initialization time.  I know that if my class was POD, or declared constexpr, that it would be guaranteed to be initialized during the "constant initialization" phase.  But is my LazyString class guaranteed to run before dynamic init?

Comment: Static initialization takes place before any dynamic initialization in the program. So your `LazyString` global object is initialized before any other object's dynamic initialization can call `LazyString::get()`.