# Can std::string copy constructor throw?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, copy-constructor, stdstring

Can the copy constructor of `std::string` throw in C++11?

*(Stackoverflow says my question does not meet its quality standards, and it seems like it just wants more prose, so here is some dummy text.)*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the low quality question and the poster's poor quality attempt to lengthen it overcome the minimum question length limit.

Comment: @marko, can you explain what the quality problem is?

Comment: We'd expect to see a bit more code than this.  SO has a minimum question length limit try and persuade better quality questions.

Comment: @marko, I see your point, but I like brevity, and I would hate to add text that serves no purpose.

Comment: @marko In general I would agree, but this question really doesn't require much code. It wouldn't add anything.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, it may be obvious to you, if you have studied `std::string` implementations, and what the standard requires about it, but otherwise it is far from obvious. For example, it seems to me that it would be possible to always copy a string object by copying the payload reference, and only clone the payload immediately before modification and before "leaks" that allow modification.

Comment: That has been addressed already on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11 so if the question is whether that's allowed, then it's a duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, thanks for digging up that link. It's certainly relevant. I don't see it as a duplicate, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can result in a memory allocation, and that can throw. So yes, it can throw.

Comment: Thanks, and that seems to be backed up by http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string.