# Test whether libstdc++'s version uses a C++11-compliant std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, libstdc++

I'm writing some C++11 code that makes assumptions about the nature of `std::string` that are valid, but represent behavior that was changed in C++11. In the earlier days, libstdc++'s `basic_string` implementation conformed to the 98/03 requirements, but not to the more strict C++11 requirements.

As I understand it, libstdc++ has fixed the issues around `basic_string`. The problem is that there are many versions of the library that people use which do not implement this fix. And my code may silently fail in many unpleasant ways on them.

I would like to have a `static_assert` fire if the user attempts to compile my library against those non-conformant versions of libstdc++. How do I detect the version, and equally importantly, which version should I look for?

Comment: can you voice your assumptions?

Comment: I believe that is required even in C++03. COW should retain this property.

Comment: @Puppy: Sorry, I said that wrong. It's better to just [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29199733/734069). Something like that.

Comment: Could you check if a `std::string` is null-terminated? If it is, you know it conforms to C++11 requirements as per C++0x FDIS 21.4.7.1/1.

Comment: @erip: That's not something you can `static_assert` on. Also, in C++98/03, it would be undefined behavior to try to access the terminator character, so it might still work even on them.

Comment: @NicolBolas why do you need a static_assert? I know they are fine - but you probably need unit-tests as well so running the test there should be good as well.

Comment: @TobiasLangner: Because most of my users will be compiling my *library*, not my tests.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That is not equivalent- the call to `s[0]` in that answer is non-`const`-qualified.

Comment: @NicolBolas then add the test to initialization in Debug-Mode. Should not take long. Take the example from the link above and do it both ways to detect COW.

Comment: @Puppy: I never said the link was equivalent; that's why I said "I said that wrong."

Comment: @TobiasLangner: Um, thanks, but no thanks.

Comment: @Tobias: You're making an assumption that his library actually *has* some one-time initialization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new C++11 compliant `std::string` was introduced with the new (dual) ABI in GCC 5 ([Runtime Library Section of the changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html)).

The macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` decides whether the old or new ABI is being used, so just check it:

```
#if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
```

Of course that's specific to libstdc++ only.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <string>

static_assert(sizeof(std::string) != sizeof(void*), "using ref-counted string");

int
main()
{
}
```

Demo:  http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P8LB79Cy6ASZlKuV

This test takes advantage of the internal workings of all of the known std::lib implementations of `std::string`, and of gcc's implementation in particular.

gcc's refcounted `string` consists of a single pointer to a dynamically allocated structure that holds the size, capacity, reference count, and data of the string.  Scott Meyers does a nice summary of string implementations in Effective STL that was accurate in the 2001 time frame.  I believe (I could be mistaken) that "implementation C" in item 15 of that book is gcc's std::string.

For short-string implementations (pretty much mandated by C++11), a `string` can no longer consist of a single pointer on the stack.  Scott's implementation D is our first look at a short-string implementation from that era.  This is the VS/Dinkumware `string`.  The `sizeof(string)` itself will contain some data buffer to hold string data with no allocations.

One can get a handle on what different implementations are doing with this short program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "word size is           " << sizeof(void*)/sizeof(char) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof string is       " << sizeof(s) << '\n';
    std::cout << "short string buffer is " << s.capacity() << '\n';
}
```

This prints out the word size, typically 4 or 8 (32 bit / 64 bit) as at least one implementation (libc++) changes its characteristics on this hardware feature.  Then it prints out the `sizeof(string)` which will be a multiple of word size, and then the `capacity()` of an empty `string`, which will be the size of the short-string buffer if it exists.

Here is a somewhat incomplete survey:

```
gcc/libstdc++ 4.8

word size is           8
sizeof string is       8
short string buffer is 0
```

---

```
gcc/libstdc++ 5.2

word size is           8
sizeof string is       32
short string buffer is 15
```

---

```
clang/libc++ -arch i386 OS X

word size is           4
sizeof string is       12
short string buffer is 10
```

---

```
clang/libc++ -arch x86_64 OS X

word size is           8
sizeof string is       24
short string buffer is 22
```

---

```
VS-2015

word size is           4
sizeof string is       24
short string buffer is 15
```

In this survey, only gcc/libstdc++ 4.8 is clearly not using a short-string optimization.  And only gcc/libstdc++ 4.8 has `sizeof(string) == 1 word`.  And this is in fact the only implementation in this survey that is using reference counting.

All in all, this test for libstdc++'s `std::string` isn't portable.  But by specification it doesn't have to be.  We can take advantage of the known history of gcc's development in this area.  The spec (the question) says it only has to work on gcc's libstdc++.

Comment: Can you explain briefly why would this do the trick? Do COW strings have only one `void*` (private) data member and of course no virtual functions?

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.

Comment: To extend the survey, VS-2013 strings have the same structure as VS-2015's.  In VS-2010 strings are an extra word size bigger (due to not optimising away the zero size std::allocator).  I put together a [summary table](http://info.prelert.com/blog/cpp-stdstring-implementations#summarytable) for the 64 bit versions of the different standard libraries, that also includes other details like the growth strategy.