# Why is sizeof(std::string) only eight bytes?

Tags: c++

Why is `std::string`'s size, as determined by `sizeof(std::string)`, yield `8`?
I thought it should be more than `8` as it has to have an `int` (`sizeof(int) == 8` on my machine) data member for giving `std::string::length()` and `std::string::size()` in O(1) and probably a `char*` for characters.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please try again.

Comment: @self: it is totally clear. He asks why sizeof(string) < sizeof(char *) + sizeof(int)

Comment: The answer probably depends on the compiler you are using.

Comment: thank you @Pierre , thats precisely my confusion, I thought string should have an int and a char* as data member so sizeof(string) >sizeof(char*)

Comment: @shanker861: it may depend on the implementation. If you do a std::string with only char *, you can use the 8 first bytes as an int, so when you do mystring[0] it's in fact mystring.ptr[8]; and str.size() = *((int *) str.ptr);

Comment: @freakish, I understand that the number (sizeof(string)==8) will depend on machine but considering string gives length in O(1) time, I though it should have an int data member to do so, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @shanker861 No, what I meant is that the actual implementation of `std::string` depends on the compiler. I.e. perhaps in your compiler `length()` is not `O(1)` at all.

Comment: @freakish you mean the STL, compiler doesn't implement the C code (actual implementation) of `std::string`

Comment: @self: If we're going to get technical, then let's say [C++ Standard Library implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about).

Comment: @Pierre, Yes, It seems that would work. Do you this how its done on GCC or other popular compiler ?

Comment: @shanker861: no i don't know exactly their implementation, but 8 is the size of a pointer on a 64bits processor, so they just use 1 attribute in their std::string class.

Comment: Ancient versions of GCC contain a non-conforming implementation of `std::string`.

Comment: If a `std::string` stores the string's length internally, it's going to be a `size_t`, not an `int`. FWIW, on the implementation I use `sizeof (std::string) == 32`. (It depends on the runtime library implementation, not on the compiler. Two different implementations might use the same compiler but different runtime libraries.

Comment: @KerrekSB: GCC doesn't contain an implementation of `std::string`; it's provided by the runtime library.

Comment: @KeithThompson: "[**The GNU Compiler Collection includes** front ends for C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Java, Ada, and Go, as well as libraries for these languages (**libstdc++**, libgcj,...).](https://gcc.gnu.org/)" GCC (the GNU Compiler Collection) includes an implementation of `std::string` in `libstdc++`. `gcc` (the compiler) does not. I don't think Kerrek SB's comment is incorrect.

Comment: @KeithThompson: GCC ships with libstdc++ as its standard library implementation of choice.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Interesting.  I know that the gcc C compiler commonly uses different C library implementations on different platforms (often glibc, but also newlib for Cygwin, the Microsoft library for MinGW, or the native library for other platforms). I'm less familiar with the C++ side. So does the MinGW implementation on Windows use the GNU libstdc++?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes. In Linux, the C library is usually very intimately tied to the kernel. For C++, GCC ships its own libstdc++ standard library implementation which is intimately tied to the compiler (i.e. you can't get it on its own). Clang goes out of its way to work with libstdc++, but there's also libc++ that's designed to work with Clang (and only Clang as far as I'm aware). There do exist third-party standard library implementations, but they're quite niche. The standard library requires a fair amount of compiler magic, so it's not so easy to reimplement.

Answer (score 42):

The implementation of `std::string` is not specified by the C++ standard. It only describes the classes behaviour. However, I would expect there to be more than one pointer's worth of information in the class. In particular:

- A pointer to the actual string.
- The size available.
- The actual size used.

It MAY of course store all these in a dynamically allocated location, and thus take up exactly the same amount of space as `char*` [in most architectures].

In fact looking at the C++ header that comes with my Linux machine, the implementation is quite clear when you look at (which, as per comments, is "pre-C++11", but I think roughly representative either way):

```
  size_type
  length() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return _M_rep()->_M_length; }
```

and then follow that to:

```
  _Rep*
  _M_rep() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return &((reinterpret_cast<_Rep*> (_M_data()))[-1]); }
```

which in turn leads to:

```
  _CharT*
  _M_data() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return  _M_dataplus._M_p; }
```

Which leads to

```
  // Data Members (private):
  mutable _Alloc_hider  _M_dataplus;
```

and then we get to:

```
  struct _Alloc_hider : _Alloc
  {
    _Alloc_hider(_CharT* __dat, const _Alloc& __a) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    : _Alloc(__a), _M_p(__dat) { }

    _CharT* _M_p; // The actual data.
  };
```

The actual data about the string is:

```
  struct _Rep_base
  {
    size_type       _M_length;
    size_type       _M_capacity;
    _Atomic_word        _M_refcount;
  };
```

So, it's all a simple pointer called `_M_p` hidden inside several layers of getters and a bit of casting...

Comment: To be fair, dynamic allocation can usually be ruled out by noexcept methods.  I do not think `std::string` has enough noexcept requirements for this to be the case.

Comment: I mean, "together with the string itself", rather than each part being dynamically allocated.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I think it is C++11, since it's from the 4.9.2 version of gcc, which is after C++11 compliance in gcc, and it mentions C++11 in the file?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thank you, very well explained.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: It's pre-C++11. The `_Atomic_word _M_refcount;` implies sharing and thus copy-on-write behaviour, which breaks the constraints of `operator[]`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12199710/1139697.

Answer (score 36):

Because all your implementation of `std::string` stores is a pointer to the heap where all of it's data is stored.

Comment: simple and best answer.

Comment: This kind of implementation is straightforward for `std::string` implementations using copy-on-write and references counting (libstdc++ did this in the C++98 ABI mode, and linux distributions are in the process of getting rid of it as default right now). C++11 made this kind of implementation illegal, so you will likely find implementations with `sizeof(std::string) == sizeof(void*)` much less in the future.

Comment: This is true as of 2019 - in Visual C++ 2019 `sizeof(std::string) == 28`

Comment: Also, 32 == sizeof(std::string) ,in clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_700/final); 24  == sizeof(std::string) ,in Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42). But sometimes on OnlineGDB ,it shows: 8 == sizeof(std::string) !!!