# size of pointer to array vs string in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, sizeof

```
string a= "Stack Overflow";
char b[]= "Stack Overflow";
cout<<sizeof(a)<<","<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
```

Output of above code is 4,15

Since 'a' points to the string, it has size 4 that of a string on my machine.

#### 'b' is also pointer to string, but why it has size of 15 (i.e. of sizeof("Stack Overflow")) ?

Comment: A simple `std::string` can be implemented containing a pointer to a dynamically buffer containing the characters in the string and a bit of bookkeeping for the length and whatnot, but there are many ways to implement a `std::string` This one happens to pack everything it needs into 4 bytes.

Comment: Related [Why is sizeof(std::string) only eight bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560502/why-is-sizeofstdstring-only-eight-bytes)

Comment: @ArunAS Not really - that's a question about how `string` happens to be implemented, this one is more fundamental.

Comment: @Barry I know, that's why I posted this so OP can know how it is implemented. That itself should help understanding this more

Comment: `a` is **not** a pointer; its the name of a `std::string` object. And in `sizeof(b)`, `b` is **not** a pointer; it's the name of an array. In most contexts, the name of an array decays into a pointer to it first element. That does not happen when the name is the argument to `sizeof`.

Comment: Actually, `std::string` typically has a size of 16 or so. It seems `string` is an alias for `char const*` in this case.

Comment: @Shivam How is "string" defined? What headers are you including? Can you show more of the code?

Comment: @AtesGoral I have included <string> header only. And <iostream> as usual

Answer (score 6):

> Since 'a' points to the string, it has size 4 that of a string on my machine.

Not exactly.

`a` **IS A** string. It is not a pointer and, hence, does not point to a string. The implementation of `string` on your setup is such that `sizeof(string)` is 4.

> 'b' is also pointer to string, but why it has size of 15 (i.e. of sizeof("Stack Overflow")) ?

Not true.

`b` is not a pointer to a string. It is an array of `char`. The line

```
char b[]= "Stack Overflow";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char b[15]= "Stack Overflow";
```

The compiler deduces the size of the array and creates an array of the right size.

Comment: Then how does `a` store large strings in only 4 bytes?

Comment: @Shivam, it contains a pointer that points to dynamically allocated data.