# sizeof pair<int,string> in c++

Tags: c++, sizeof

In the following code (on a 32 bit machine), if I print out the sizeof the pair, should I get 12? In my compiler I got 16. Is this always the case or it is compiler specific?

```
pair<int,string> b = std::make_pair(1,"randomcrap");
string c= "randomcrap";
cout << sizeof(c) << endl; //got 8 which make sense
cout << sizeof(b) << endl; //got 16
```

Comment: All compilers have padding so that the fields in a struct or class align to word boundaries.  You can remove the padding with a compiler option and then it might be 12.

Comment: `sizeof c` is going to be implementation-dependent.

Comment: Actually I think it is supposed to be 16 for some compilers.  An int is 4, but how large do you thing a string is?  With g++ it's 12.  A g++ std::string has a pointer to the heap, an int for the current size of the string and an int for the actual allocated capacity.  That makes size() be O(n)  but takes an extra 4 bytes.  But it differs by compiler.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560502/why-is-sizeofstdstring-only-eight-bytes

Comment: In your case it is definitely padding because your std::string is only 8...

Comment: By `string` do you mean `std::string` or something else? I don't see how `std::string` can have a size of only 8