# Why there is so much gap in address of two vector elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm learning about vectors in c++. On printing address of two adjacent `vector<string>` elements I'm getting result which is confusing me a little bit.
**Program**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {  
   vector<string> word;

   //Enter any two words
     string ch;
     for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
      {
       getline(cin,ch);
       word.push_back(ch);
       }

   //Display the words
     for(auto i:word)
      {
       cout<<i<<" ";
      }  
     cout<<endl;

    //Display address of first two elements

      cout<<word.data()<<" "<<(word.data()+1)<<endl;

     return 0;
  }
```

**INPUT Data:** hello
                  world
  **OUTPUT :**  `hello world`
               `0x1b9f060 0x1b9f080`
What I'm not getting is that there are only 10 character in total(5 in first input and another five in second)and each character take 1 byte space.
So why there is gap of 20 bytes between both vector elements?
I checked with **vector<int>** but the gap was only of `four` bytes.

Comment: You're really asking what `sizeof(string)` is.

Comment: `cout<<sizeof(word[1])` is giving 32.

Comment: Those are 32 bytes, the addresses are printed with base 16 (hexadecimal).

Comment: what I'm trying to say is if it is 32 byte then difference should be more than 20 between both the addresses. &Ulrich

Comment: It is hexadecimal, not decimal. `0x` in the front.

Comment: Compare `0x20`  (the difference between the two addresses printed) with `sizeof(std::string)`.   There will be a distinct relationship.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is sizeof(std::string) only eight bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560502/why-is-sizeofstdstring-only-eight-bytes)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the actual "gap" is 32 bytes since the addresses are hexadecimal values `0x1b9f080 - 0x1b9f060 = 0x20 = 32`.

This is the size of the element of the `vector` which in this case is `std::string`. Most importantly `std::string` is a class and its size is roughly determined by the sizes of its members just like any other class.

What are the actual members of `std::string` and what size does it have as the result is dependent on the implementation of the standard library you are currently using. The most important thing, however, is that the size of `std::string` **doesn't depend at all** on the length of the actual string it's storing because it only holds a pointer to it and the string itself is located elsewhere (on the heap).

Comment: Is this also a big difference between C++ `std::string and C string ?

Comment: @user4156958, yes, but you can't really adequately compare those because they are different entities altogether. In C a string is just an array of `char`s, while `std::string` is a class that hides this array from you and manages it itself.

Comment: `std::string` is C++ specific.   It is not part of C at all.

Answer (score 1):

A `string` is not an array of characters, it's a pointer to an allocated space (of given size) that contains what you think is the string. There is usually also additional information like the actual size of the string (because C++ strings can have a `\0` character in them), the allocated space perhaps...

There are exceptions, like Small Array Optimizations, but let's say it's not your actual string for the sake of clarity.

The `int` in your `vector<int>` has a size of `4`, that's what we expect indeed.

Comment: So string in C and c++ are totally different? @matthieu Brucher

Comment: Yes. How would you store a variable length string otherwise in a vector?