# Size of string vs size of char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stdstring

I have to write a piece of code and deploy it in a system with limited memory space and was thinking about char arrays vs string . I wrote the following piece of code to get a better idea.

```
    string str="abcde";
    char carray[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
    cout <<"size of char array:"<< sizeof(carray) << endl ;
    cout <<"size of string:"<< sizeof(str) << endl ;
```

The output I get is

```
size of char array:6
size of string:28
```

So, I have 2 questions

1. Can I conclude that using the string will be a foolish idea given that it is taking much more space, given that memory space is tight and the max chars in my array wont be greater than 10?
2. Why the hell is size of string  showing as 28? on what basis?

Comment: For `std::string`, use `str.size()`  function

Comment: I compiled this on my laptop and it gave me: `size of char array:6 size of string:4`. This has me even more confused, towards why would a 5-character string occupy only 4 bytes...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is sizeof(std::string) only eight bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560502/why-is-sizeofstdstring-only-eight-bytes)

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is the size of `std::string` object - a compile-time constant. It's unrelated to the length of the character sequence this object manages (which could vary at run time). That length is reported by `str.size()` or `str.length()` member functions.

Comment: @Inian : what I think is that size() function returns the number of chars inside the string object, not the size it has taken in memory

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: I am concerned about memory usage and not the number of characters

Comment: Consider: `char* p =  new char[100];`. Here, `sizeof(p)` is the amount of memory the pointer itself occupies (usually 4 or 8), and is unrelated to the size of the block of memory it points to. So which value do you care about - 4/8, or 100?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : I got your point. would you suggest the std::string or char[] for smaller char arrays .for approx maximum 10 chars

Comment: Use `string` everywhere.

Comment: Rather depends on what you plan to do with those arrays. Are you going to have so many of them that the overhead of `std::string` would become an issue? What kinds of operations would you need to perform on them?

Comment: There will be thousands of them.. small ones but big in number.. they will act more like constants.. means once assigned some value.. they wont be changed

Comment: Depends on what you're going to do with the string, how permanent it is, and just how tight the memory constraints are. I start with `std::string` and only migrate to `char` arrays when examination of the program tells me that have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` is a `class` object in C++. The size of it is implementation-defined, but will generally require space for *at least* both a pointer to a heap-allocated string, and a size. The `sizeof(std::string)` you are seeing may be specific to your implementation -- but it could be partially due to a small-buffer optimization where small strings are stored directly in the string.

An array of `char`s is just an array of characters, so `sizeof(arr)` will always be the the number of characters.

---

As for whether you can use `std::string`: it depends on how constrained you are. `std::string` will often use heap memory for larger strings, which may be hard to justify on extremely constrained systems. However, most `std::string` implementations also have support for small-buffer-optimized strings, where these strings are stored directly in the `std::string` rather than indirectly via heap memory

If heap memory is not justifyable, `std::string` will not be a good solution for you.

However, if that's the case, I would recommend you look into either adopting an existing `static_string` implementation that encodes the size as a template argument, or at least writing your own. This would be better than using `char` arrays everywhere, since this becomes hard to manage long-term.

Comment: Sounds like this will be the accepted answer. Just a couple of points. There will be thousands of them and once assigned some value they wont be changed. small ones but big in number. so heap memory is a bit of a catch here. But that static implementation  I am going to try.

Comment: If it's thousands of them, then heap memory is definitely a tough pill to swallow in a constrained system... `static_string` is probably your best bet. There are many open-source implementations of similar concepts available out there -- so it's a good place to start