# Conditional assignment of references

Tags: c++, gcc

Can someone with a deeper understanding of the C++ standard than me please elaborate on this?

This is my example program

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const std::string message("hello world");
    std::cout << std::hex << (void*)message.c_str() << std::endl;
    const std::string& toPrint = (argc > 0) ? message : "";
    std::cout << std::hex << (void*)toPrint.c_str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On one machine it does this:

```
# g++ --version && g++ str_test.cpp && ./a.out                  
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

0x9851014
0x9851014
```

`message` and `toPrint` seem to refer to the same instance as I would expect. However, on another machine, this happens:

```
# g++ --version && g++ str_test.cpp && ./a.out 
g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

0x7ffeb9ab4ac0
0x7ffeb9ab4ae0
```

Here it looks like the compiler constructed a copy of `message` for `toPrint` to point at.

What behavior is correct according to the C++ standard? Or is it undefined in general?

Comment: Could you please reduce your code by removing (? :) operator and check again?

Comment: @SergeiNikulov I suspect that the conditional operator is essential to the observed behaviour. However, I wouldn't mind if MBober printed `argc` for demonstrating that it infact is always true.

Comment: @SergeiNikulov user2079303 That's right. This is just a simple example. I need to know the behavior of the ? operator and needed a condition that is always true but cannot be optimized out. But FYI, when I make this a simple assignment, the code behaves on GCC 5 the same as GCC 4.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe argc is always at least 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Martin Bonner explains why the address could be the same even for a copy of the string.

To explain, why the `message and toPrint seem to refer to the same instance as I would expect.` is misguided, I shall quote the standard.

Let's first explore what conversion is needed (I suppose it's not the question here, but just for completeness). Ignore the first *otherwise*. It refers to the case of `void` type expressions.

> [expr.cond]/3 Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other. The process for determining whether an operand expression `E1` of type `T1` can be converted to match an operand expression `E2` of type `T2` is deﬁned as follows:
>
> - If `E2` is an lvalue: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted to the type "lvalue reference to `T2`", subject to the constraint that in the conversion the reference must bind directly to an lvalue. **(cannot bind lvalue reference of type `std::string` to a strig literal)**
> - If `E2` is an xvalue: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted to the type "rvalue reference to `T2`", subject to the constraint that the reference must bind directly. **(no xvalues here)**
> - If `E2` is an rvalue or if neither of the conversions above can be done and at least one of the operands has (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - if `E1` and `E2` have class type, and the underlying class types are the same or one is a base class of the other: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if the class of `T2` is the same type as, or a base class of, the class of `T1`, and the cv-qualification of `T2` is the same cv-qualification as, or a greater cv-qualification than, the cv-qualification of `T1`. If the conversion is applied, `E1` is changed to a prvalue of type `T2` by copy-initializing a temporary of type `T2` from `E1` and using that temporary as the converted operand. **(string literal has no class type)**
>   - Otherwise (i.e., if `E1` or `E2` has a nonclass type, or if they both have class types but the underlying classes are not either the same or one a base class of the other): `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted to the type that expression `E2` would have if `E2` were converted to a prvalue (or the type it has, if `E2` is a prvalue). **(this applies)**

The final bullet covers this case. The string literal has a nonclass type and it can be converted to match a `std::string` prvalue.

Now, let's explore how the conversion affects the result.

> 4 If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type **(they are not)**, the result
>   is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if
>   both are bit-fields.
>
> 5 Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be applied to the operands (13.3.1.2, 13.6). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this section.

So, the result is a prvalue! It's not a lvalue reference. How do you get a prvalue from an lvalue?

> 6 Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the second and third operands. After those conversions, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type. If the operands have
>     class type  **(they do after the conversion)**, the result is a **prvalue temporary** of the result type, which is copy-initialized from either
>     the second operand or the third operand depending on the value of the first operand.

So, we know that the result will be copy-initialized from the operand expression. Even though, we assign a reference, and the operand of the conditional is an lvalue reference to the same type, the reference will be bound to a temporary, copied from the operand.

If you had used another lvalue reference to `const std::string` as the third operand, then you would have simply assigned the to the lvalue, rather than to a temporary prvalue.

Answer (score 6):

You are being confused by GLIBCs copy-on-write string sharing.  Change your test program to:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const std::string message("hello world");
    std::cout << std::hex << (void*)&message << std::endl;
    const std::string& toPrint = (argc > 0) ? message : "";
    std::cout << std::hex << (void*)&toPrint << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(in other words print the address of the string object, not the address of the contained text), and both platforms will return different addresses.

The latest standard has forbidden copy-on-write (although I don't understand how exactly).  Prior to that it was legal, but not mandatory.  (Current thinking is that 'small string optimization' does better than cow - particularly in a multithreaded world).

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Gosh that question got bad-tempered quickly, didn't it!

Comment: As soon as you remove the conditional operator, the addresses are identical again: https://ideone.com/30RXhk

Comment: @dasdingonesin that's because there are no conversions needed in that example.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of COW strings before.