# Possible gcc bug: String data not being shared in containers of string on first reassignment of result

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Demonstrates *possible* bug that appears as early as GCC-4.7 up to GCC-5.1 (at least). Affecting C++11, C++14, but not C++98 (assuming 98's inability to elide the copy has the same effect as `generate_strings_v2`).

Is this an error or misunderstanding on my part, or a legitimate bug?

**Edit:** This question asks how the contents of functions that should return identical results are able to impact data sharing in an external assignment. However, as it turns out, implementations of `std::string` utilizing copy-on-write are non-compliant for modern C++, making this an non-issue.

```
// or using deque/list makes no difference.
using stringset = std::vector<std::string>;

// @bug strings do not share data on first reassignment of result.
stringset generate_strings_v1(int count, int length)
{
    stringset set(count);
    for (auto& x : set) {
        x.resize(length);
        std::fill(x.begin(), x.end(), 'a');
    }
    return set;
}

// works as expected.
stringset generate_strings_v2(int count, int length)
{
    stringset set(count);
    for (auto& x : set) {
        x.resize(length);
        std::fill(x.begin(), x.end(), 'a');
    }
    return stringset(set);
}

void test(const char* header, std::function<stringset(int, int)> genstrings,
    int count, int length)
{
    auto data_ptr_eq = [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
    {
        return a.data() == b.data();
    };

    stringset a = genstrings(count, length);
    stringset b = a;

    if (std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), data_ptr_eq))
        std::cout << header << " : data pointer match\n";
    else {
        std::cout << header << " : data pointer mismatch\n";
        assert(a == b); // not expected; just in case.
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int count = 1, length = 1;
    assert(length > 0 && count > 0);

    test("v1", generate_strings_v1, count, length);
    test("v2", generate_strings_v2, count, length);
    return 0;
}
```

Extended code and output may be viewed [here](https://ideone.com/OH53j3).

Comment: From what I can tell, copy on write isn't conforming to standard. Those tests should output mismatch

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11

Comment: @Danh Thanks for the link. I didn't realize copy on write was non-conforming since C++11. I guess that makes this a non-issue.