# Comparing 2 std::lists of std::pairs - Keeping Unique and Different elements

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 Lists of Pairs, each having matching pairs, non matching pairs, and unique pairs. I want to keep the unique and non matching pairs.

I made this code, which works great for finding the mismatches, but not the unique:

```
std::list <std::pair<std::string,std::string>> outputList1;
std::list <std::pair<std::string,std::string>> outputList2;
for (auto x: outputList1){
  for (auto y: outputList2){
  //compare x to y
         if(x.first == y.first)
         {
                   if(x.second != y.second)
                   {
                        //mismatch on the second element
                        //do something with it
                    }


        }

  }
}
```

This is what I tried to pull in the unique. I tried to check to see if I am at the last element of y, and if so, save that pair to pull out the unique elements, but it is pulling in everything. I tried writing this out on paper, but my head is spinning.

```
  auto &last = *(--outputList2.end());
  for (auto x: outputList1){
  for (auto& y: outputList2){
  //compare x to y
         if(x.first == y.first)
         {
                   if(x.second != y.second)
                   {
                       //mistmatch found so I save it off somewhere
                    }


        }
        else if(&y == &last)
         {
             //unique item found in list x
         }

  }
}
```

I also tried this to get the end of y on the else if:

```
        else if(&y == &*std::prev(std::end(outputList2)))
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just BTW `for (auto x: outputList1)` this makes a copy of those two strings for each element. This could potentially be very slow. Change to `auto&` or `const auto&`.

Comment: I wonder if [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) is what you need.  It does require the set to be sorted though.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I understood well, it would rather be [`set_symmetric_difference()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/)

Comment: I'm a bit hazy on the semantical differences between "unique" and "non-matching". But if you want to find all unique pairs, that occur only once in the collective lists, that's easy: `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int> n; for (const auto &p: outputList1) ++n[p]; for (const auto &p: outputList2) ++n[p];` - now extract all keys from the map whose value is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you search for `std::set_symmetric_difference`. In other words, you want to do something with all elements except those that exist in both lists (the matching ones). In other words, you want to discard the intersection. That is what `std::set_symmetric_difference` is build of.

The thing with `std::set_difference` and `std::set_symmetric_difference` is the ranges must be sorted. So, we sort the lists first, but in another lists to keep the original lists untouched and using reference wrappers to avoid so many copies of the inner pairs, sorting the references to those pairs. Since `std::reference_wrapper` has no defined `operator<`, we need to pass a comparator (a lambda function):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

using pair_t = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using pair_cref = std::reference_wrapper<const pair_t>;

int main()
{
    std::list<pair_t> outputList1{{"c", "b"}, {"a", "g"}, {"0", "f"}};
    std::list<pair_t> outputList2{{"c", "d"}, {"0", "f"}, {"z", "1"}};

    std::list<pair_cref> sorted_view_1(outputList1.begin(), outputList1.end());
    std::list<pair_cref> sorted_view_2(outputList2.begin(), outputList2.end());

    auto less_f = [](const pair_cref& a, const pair_cref& b)
         { return a.get() < b.get(); };

    sorted_view_1.sort(less_f);
    sorted_view_2.sort(less_f);

    std::list<pair_cref> unmatchs_and_uniques;
    std::set_symmetric_difference(sorted_view_1.begin(), sorted_view_1.end(),
                                  sorted_view_2.begin(), sorted_view_2.end(),
                                  std::back_inserter(unmatchs_and_uniques), less_f);

    for (const auto& p : unmatchs_and_uniques)
        std::cout << p.get().first << ", " << p.get().second << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a, g
c, b
c, d
z, 1
```

Coliru [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/168f6b7676b0ee12).

If you don't mind to modify the original lists, you can just do:

```
outputList1.sort();
outputList2.sort();
```

instead of creating the sorted views, and apply `std::set_symmetric_difference` directly over the `outputListx`.

The code is a bit more readable, though not shorter. In any case, that solution is faster, because yours has a

[image: yours]

complexity order, while using `std::list::sort` and `std::set_symmetric_difference`, the complexity order of the algorithm is the one of `sort()` (`std::set_symmetric_difference` has linear order):

[image: mine]

being `nx` the size of the longest list.

Comment: I believe gcc no longer has a copy on write string.  It if also disallowed by the standard

Comment: Disallowed? Any known reason for that?

Comment: Fyi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11

Comment: @Peregring-lk Thanks for the reply man! This looks pretty good. Let me soak on this for a couple of days!

Comment: @Peregring-lk I just used this and it works brilliantly. I think you just educated me and saved me about 3 months of struggle in that brief code there. You rock.

Comment: @Behuvius Thanks for your words.