# How is C++ memory managed when a string value is assigned and later changed by assigning another value?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I really need to understand how the memory is managed in C++ for the below cases:

Case-1:

```
string s1 = "ABCD";
s1= "EFGH";
```

**What happens in the memory w.r.t the string value "ABCD"? Does it automatically get deallocated? Or is it a memory leak here?**

Case-2:

```
char* val = "ABCD";
val = "EFGH";
```

**Similar to Case-1, how is Case-2 different from Case-1?**

Case-3:

```
string s1 = "ABCD";
string s2 = s1;
```

**Is separate memory allocated to s2 with value "ABCD"? Or do s1 and s2 point to the same memory location here? 
How is memory managed in this case?**

Please share a link to study in depth on these? Any suggestions will definitely help me.

Comment: *Please share a link to study in depth on these?* -- None of those examples will leak memory.

Comment: *Or do s1 and s2 point to the same memory location here?* -- And what if `s2` changes values?  Does `s1` change also?  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It sounds like it, and it isn't that strange. It's copy-on-write and that is how Qt's strings work. Edit : Turns out a bunch of Qt objects use it.

Comment: An important reason for using `std::string` is that *you don't need to worry about memory management*. What actually happens is an implementation detail that isn't specified in the standard. The `char*` example is just reassigning a pointer from one static string to another, so there's no memory management to worry about there either.

Comment: `char* val` needs to be `const char* val`

Answer (score 1):

1. Modern `std::string` implementations roughly follows these rules(Well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319672/3656081) too):

   - Short Strings(<=26 chars?) are allocated on the stack using an optimization called SSO.
   - Strings longer than than are allocated on the heap. The std::string implementation internally manages both the allocations and deallocations here.
2. `const char* x = "ABCD"` is allocated <strike>on the stack</strike> in static storage and a pointer to it is stored on the stack. This can be seen in the CE link [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v7VaU9), where `rsp:rsp-8` is made to point to `.LC0`.

Given the above observations:

- Case 1: Its allocating x on the stack and then copying the new value "EFGH" to s1 without allocating any more stack space. [CE Link](https://godbolt.org/z/VoMGRK)
- Case 2: It makes `val` point to the static storage where "ABCD" is stored and then to where "EFGH" is. [CE Link](https://godbolt.org/z/VZFAj3)
- Case 3: This will(with no optimizations enabled) allocate 2 std::strings on the stack([CE Link](https://godbolt.org/z/WoeSiV)), following from Case 1.

As noted in the comments, alternative `std::string` implementations are possible for example (1) Those that don't implement SSO (2) Implement copy-on-write.

Comment: I've rewritten parts of the answer to reflect your comments @walnut

Comment: As noted in the other answer, since C++11, copy-on-write implementations aren't really possible anymore, which is what I wasn't sure about on the spot when I wrote my previous comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11.

Answer (score 1):

### Case 1

```
string s1 = "ABCD";
```

`string` handles memory allocation to store `"ABCD"` for you. The `string` destructor will be called automatically when `s1` goes out of scope which will free memory allocated by the `string`.

```
s1 = "EFGH";
```

A `string` copy assignment operator will overwrite the memory storing `"ABCD"` with `"EFGH"`.

### Case 2

```
char* val = "ABCD";
val = "EFGH";
```

Fred Larson answered this question in the comments above, you're just reassigning a pointer to a static string. The stack will allocate memory only for the pointer (not the data), and the pointer will be automatically deallocated when `val` goes out of scope.

### Case 3

```
string s1 = "ABCD";
string s2 = s1;
```

`s2` will allocate memory and copy `s1`. A copy on write implementation of the copy assignment operator would only allocate and copy memory if `s2` is mutated. However, as of C++11 it seems that COW implementations of `std::string` are no longer allowed ([Legality of COW std::string implementation in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11)).

### Case 4

Here is an example of a scenario where you *do* need to worry about freeing allocated memory.

You might use this if you need a `string` to outlive the scope in which it was created. (In practice, you should usually avoid this approach. See **Case 5** below.)

```
string* s1 = new string("ABCD");
delete s1;
```

In this example `string` is still internally managing memory to store `"ABCD"`, but the `string` pointer is heap allocated and the `string` destructor will not be called when `s1` goes out of scope. In this case you are responsible for using `delete` to ensure the memory is cleaned up when `s1` is no longer required.

### Case 5

```
shared_ptr<string> s1 = make_shared<string>("EFGH");
```

`shared_ptr` is usually the way to go versus `new` and `delete`. Shared pointers prevent a lot of memory leaks due to programming mistakes. `shared_ptr` handles `delete` for you, and uses reference counting to keep the `string` alive until the last reference has been destroyed.

Comment: In most cases, I would say, `std::unique_ptr` is preferred over `std::shared_ptr`. The latter only makes sense if the object ownership is actually going to be shared.