# Sharing string in c++?

Tags: c++

In my class I have the following c'tor:

```
std::string obj_from;
std::string obj_to;


travel (std::string &from, std::string &to) : obj_from(from), obj_to(to)
{}
```

But since I'm giving a reference will the new object point to the given string? I mean will the string be shared between two things?

Comment: What are `obj_from` and `obj_to`? Just plain `std::string`s, or maybe references?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat plain string like this: std::string obj_from;

Comment: You need to show the declaration of your class to answer this question. `from` and `to` go out of scope once the constructor is done, so their types only prevent a copy (or not), but change nothing about `obj_from`.

Comment: since you are using the initializer list without some special cast, you will invoke the copy constructor, so `obj_from` `obj_to` will contains 2 new strings

Comment: `travel` contains two copies. That are not references.

Comment: It's arguments are reference notice the & sign @ThomasSablik

Comment: When constructed this way, it is only "shared" if your class also stores a _reference_ (or similar, _e.g._ `std::reference_wrapper`)

Comment: `from` and `to` are references but `obj_from` and `obj_to` aren't. `obj_from` and `obj_to` are copies of the objects `from` and `to` pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

In general the answer is no. You create new, separate strings.

Pre-C++11, `std::string` implementations were [allowed to share](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199710/2752075) the underlying character array between several strings, and some compilers did it, but it's no longer the case.

If your strings are so long that you *need* them to share memory, you could use something like `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`.

---

FYI, a better way to write this constructor would be:

```
travel(std::string from, std::string to)
    : obj_from(std::move(from)), obj_to(std::move(to))
{}
```

Unlike the one you use, it lets you pass temporary and/or `const` strings as parameters, while avoiding unnecessary copies.

```
travel a("foo", "bar");
const std::string x = "baz";
travel b(x, x);
```

Comment: How about `travel(const std::string& from, const std::string& to) : obj_from(from), obj_to(to) {}`.

Comment: @PaulSanders It would also work, but it copies the strings even when a move is enough.

Answer (score 1):

No, in this line

```
travel (std::string &from, std::string &to) : obj_from(from), obj_to(to) {}
```

you call the constructors of class members (copy constructors in this case). They create two different objects - obj_from and obj_to. The only limitation is that you can provide only lvalues to to the travel constructor. To make it universal you can convert it to:

```
travel (const std::string &from, const std::string &to) : obj_from(from), obj_to(to) {}
```