# Max capacity for FBString?

Tags: c++, string, folly

For [FBString](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/9eef9f866e833e3adea5e3841f673773cba47641/folly/FBString.h#L1191), *max_size()* simply returns *std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()*. However, the higher two bits of *capacity_* in *struct MediumLarge* is used to denotes the type of FBString(small/medium/large), which means the max of capacity_ will be 2^62-1(64-bit processor), it's less than the max value of *size_t*. Do I misunderstand the implementation or is this actually a bug?

```
  struct MediumLarge {
    Char* data_;
    size_t size_;
    size_t capacity_;

    size_t capacity() const {
      return kIsLittleEndian ? capacity_ & capacityExtractMask : capacity_ >> 2;
    }

    void setCapacity(size_t cap, Category cat) {
      capacity_ = kIsLittleEndian
          ? cap | (static_cast<size_t>(cat) << kCategoryShift)
          : (cap << 2) | static_cast<size_t>(cat);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBString.md) for `folly::FBString` claims to be:

> 100% compatible with `std::string`

it actually **seems to be a bug** (in my opinion).

BTW, for *large* strings, `FBString` applies *copy-on-write* (COW), which also breaks the compatibility with `std::string` (since C++11).

See [Legality of COW std::string implementation in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199710/580083) for more details.

I would guess that they simply do not care about strings of unrealistic lengths (nowadays). The incompatibility due to COW might be much more severe.